# Form submits multiple data with ajax post

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Ok so I have this app in phonegap and jquery. Here is what it does.
shows the user a form, uploads and image, and then show a confim dialog. On the confirm dialog there is the option to upload again. Now seeing as how this is all in jquery and jqMobile, it is all just one page.

When I submit the upload the first time it works perfect. When I upload it a second time it runs the post twice. 
I have posted the code below. It is like something is not being set.

```
function sendImage(src) {

    // comming from library or camera
    src = (src == 'library') ? Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;

    // get the image from phone
    navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, {quality: 45, sourceType: src});

    // got image no fuckin display it
    function success(imageData) {
        //var params = {image: imageData};
        $('#u_image').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
        $('#image').val(imageData); //image info do not add base64 or it will be unreadable when uploaded
        // send the data
        $('#upload_form').submit(function(event){
            var isConnected = checkConnection();
            if(isConnected == 1){
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = $(this).serialize();//SET THE POST DATA
                alert('uploading');
                //POST FORM TO SERVER AND GET 1 OR 0
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://site.com/index.php/mobile/do_image',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    crossDomain:true,
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response == 1) {
                            $('#image').val('');
                            $('#title').val('');
                            $('#u_image').attr('src', '');
                            $('#description').val('');
                            $.mobile.changePage("#confirm");
                        }//END SUCCESS
                        else { 
                            $('#image').val('');
                            $('#title').val('');
                            $('#u_image').attr('src', '')
                            $('#description').val('');
                            alert('There was an error. Please Try again');
                        }
                    }
                });//ENDS THE AJAX CALL
                return false;
            }// End if for connection check
            else {
                //not connected? go to login page
                $('#image').val('');
                $('#title').val('');
                $('#u_image').attr('src', '')
                $('#description').val('');
                $('#username').val('');
                document.location.href="#login_sec";
                alert('You are NOT connected to the internet!'); 
            }
        });     
    }

    function fail(message) { alert(message); }
}

$('.send-image').click(function () {
    sendImage($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to the `submit` event for your form inside a function that is being run more than once. Move the `$('#upload_form').submit(function(event){...});` code outside of the `sendImage` function so that it only binds once.

Try this:

```
function sendImage(src) {

    // comming from library or camera
    src = (src == 'library') ? Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;

    // get the image from phone
    navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, {quality: 45, sourceType: src});

    // got image no fuckin display it
    function success(imageData) {
        //var params = {image: imageData};
        $('#u_image').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
        $('#image').val(imageData); //image info do not add base64 or it will be unreadable when uploaded
        // send the data (NOTICE that I trigger the submit event here rather than binding code to the submit event)
        $('#upload_form').trigger('submit');
    }

    function fail(message) { alert(message); }
}

//NOTICE I have moved this code outside the function it was in so that it only binds once (you won't get multiple events firing this way)
$('#upload_form').submit(function(event){
    var isConnected = checkConnection();
    if(isConnected == 1){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();//SET THE POST DATA
        alert('uploading');
        //POST FORM TO SERVER AND GET 1 OR 0
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://site.com/index.php/mobile/do_image',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain:true,
            cache:false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == 1) {
                    $('#image').val('');
                    $('#title').val('');
                    $('#u_image').attr('src', '');
                    $('#description').val('');
                    $.mobile.changePage("#confirm");
                }//END SUCCESS
                else { 
                    $('#image').val('');
                    $('#title').val('');
                    $('#u_image').attr('src', '')
                    $('#description').val('');
                    alert('There was an error. Please Try again');
                }
            }
        });//ENDS THE AJAX CALL
        return false;
    }// End if for connection check
    else {
        //not connected? go to login page
        $('#image').val('');
        $('#title').val('');
        $('#u_image').attr('src', '')
        $('#description').val('');
        $('#username').val('');
        document.location.href="#login_sec";
        alert('You are NOT connected to the internet!'); 
    }
});     


$('.send-image').click(function () {
    sendImage($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I can not believe I missed that. Rookie mistake. And there goes 3 hours I'll never get back.